# Get $this variable content

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter 2 for my project.
I want to know if It is possible to get `$this` content every time's executed inside a class ?.

For example :

when I write `$this->products_model->all()`

I want get `products_model` and load `products_model`  like :

```
$this->load->model('products_models')
```

before the instruction to be executed.

Thank you.

Comment: `$this` is a pointer to the instance of the class that you're in.

Comment: Yes. You can use `$this` within you class.

Comment: as long as whatever function you're calling was called as a method (e.g. `$foo->bar()`) and not statically (`$foo::bar()`), then yes, `$this` will be available.

Comment: It is possible to create a trigger before function call? For example : trigger for `$this->products_model->all()`

Comment: Are you looking to do a model autoloader?

Comment: Yes but only when used (Lazy loading for models)